# Pose-Graph Optimization in MATLAB does not give expected results

Tags: slam, visual-odometry

I am trying to optimize a pose graph I created in MATLAB using either the `optimizePoses(viewSet)`-function on the imageViewSet that I have or the `optimizePoseGraph(poseGraph)`-function after converting that imageViewSet to a poseGraph using `createPoseGraph(vSet)`.
Both functions do not optimize the pose graph correctly.
This is the uncorrected pose graph, with loop closures in red:
[image: uncorrected pose graph]

and this is the pose graph after the optimization:

[image: optimized pose graph]

Clearly, the optimization is not correct. I used a dataset from Sensefly, and you can look at the "ground-truth" here: https://senseflycom.s3.amazonaws.com/datasets/small-village-merlishachen/postflight-report/merlischachen_report.pdf
As you see, the UAV flew some kind of a grid-trajectory.
I don't have a real clue where to start looking for the problem. There seems to be an issue with the distribution of the error over all poses.
The graph was created using visual odometry, i. e. matching features and calculating and decomposing homographies between consecutive images.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
If you need more information, feel free to ask.

Comment: Have you tried to optimize a simulated simple graph? e.g. 4 nodes and 1 edges and 1 loop closure constraint.

Comment: your result looks like the smoothness constraint is missing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried a simple graph with four nodes, four edges and 1 loop closure and that works perfectly fine. 
What do you mean by smoothness constraint, and how can I add that in MATLAB? I thought the smoothness of the graph should already come from the fact, that the overall error of the poses is minimized.

Comment: If you look at the optimized graph, loops are closed ad intended but their relative location to the neighbour nods are severely distorted. Relative transformation between close neighbor nodes shouldn't be too different after the optimization. This is sometimes called as smoothness constraint or it has many other names. Just see what are given as edges.

Comment: If you have a trajectory with n1 n2 n3 n4 nodes, your edge constraint between (n1,n2) and (n2,n3) and (n3,n4) should be given to the optimizer. I think your optimization missed it but if there are edges see what happened to the residuals after the optimization.

Comment: I calculated the pairwise distances in x-, y- and z-direction for adjacent nodes before and after the optimization, and for many pairs these distances have changed significantly. That should not be the case, right? 
Could it be a problem, that the distance in z-direction between two nodes is always in the range of 10^(-1), meaning the camera did not move in that direction at all, while in x- and y-direction the distance is around 10^4 to 10^6? After the optimization, some of the distances in the z-direction are much higher, around 10^3.